# Only make a row visible to a certified person

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a worksheet where people can add issues. I want to add user access to certain groups in this file. I've added a column where the creator of the issue has to be filled in. Checking this column, excel should determine who can see the specific row. For example:

1. Group 1 can see everything
2. Group 2 can see everything , but not the issue added by group 1
3. Group 3 can see everything , but not the issue added by groups 2 and 1

I was first thinking of adding different passwords to the file. According to the password, excel knows in which group the user belongs. (For example password "1" is for people from group 1, password "2" is for people from group 2 , ... ) But since I'm fairly new to using MS office / vba I have no idea if this is even possible.

Is this possible to add these passwords or is it possible to make a row invisible to users depending on the input of 1 cell  ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is possible, but not simple.  It will require a combination of worksheet protections and your own subroutines that will hide and unhide rows accordingly.  You will need to use worksheet protection to prevent users from manually unhiding rows.  Then, add a userform that prompts the user for a password.  Based on the password provided, you can unhide specific rows (I would recommend using an xlVeryHidden sheet that holds a list of which rows are unlocked by which passwords).  Your userform should not unprotect the sheet, but should still be able to edit the hidden property itself (so I would recommend using UI protection only)